# Materialize slider - How to include more than 4 images?

Tags: html, css, slider, materialize

I am using the image slider from materialize and the problem is that if I have more than (the pre defined) 4 images, the 5th etc is placed outside of the slider. How can I add an image AND the corresponding dot if the materialize html code doesn't include any dots..
Also, how can I add text to the images? The problem is that I don't know how to style or add things because the html from materialize doesn't include too many things. so based on which images is displayed, the corresponding text should be displayed. Ive googled so much but can't find any answers.
Thanks!

Thats the materialize code:

html

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/1"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/2"> <!-- random image -->
        <div class="caption left-align">
          <h3>Left Aligned Caption</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/3"> <!-- random image -->
    <div class="caption right-align">
      <h3>Right Aligned Caption</h3>
      <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.  </h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption center-align">
          <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
          <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.       </h5>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
});
```

Comment: Just keep on adding more of these <li>....</li> and inside the  <ul></ul> tags. You might have added it outside the <ul> by mistake and thats probably the reason its being displayed outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each slide is defined as a list item within the unordered list.  Therefore all you need to do is add another `<li></li>`  to your `<ul></ul>`.  [Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEyGWX?editors=1010)

Comment: No, thats what I did- the problem is that if I add a <li></li> that image is not being displayed insight the slider- thats why I am asking.

Comment: @javascripting Did you look at the example link I posted?

Comment: Oh I missed that. Yeah your works.thank you. What I did was really just also adding a 5th <li></li> but nothing was working..so strange!